# Nhibernate throws Object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Entity]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Object[]]'

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

using nhibernate as ORM
Trying to get one entity

```
   var users = GetUsersData(repository);
   return users.Where(f => f.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();//there is an exception
```

exception:

> Object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Entity]' cannot be
>   converted to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Object[]]'.

but when i do it that way:

```
var users = GetUsersData(repository);
return users.Where(f => f.Id == id).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
```

it runs fine.
Point me, what's wrong?

in `GetUsersData` i do :

```
private static IQueryable<User> GetUsersData(IUserRepository repository)
        {
            return repo.GetAll().Select(user => new User
                {
                    Id = user.Id,
                    Phones = user.Phones.Select(s => new Phone() { Number = s.Number }),
                    ...
                }).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: `.AsQueryable()` might be the problem. Also why Selecting the user into another user? `repo.GetAll().Where(f => f.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();` should be enough no?

Comment: `.AsQueryable() might be the problem.` it is. thx a lot. but i don't get the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.AsQueryable()` will wrap the given IQueryable from NH needlessly into a new Queryable but since NH will by default use object arrays as results and transform it later it will fail casting.

Also Selecting the user into another User will prevent changetracking and is needless copying.

```
repo.GetAll().Where(f => f.Id == id).FirstOrDefault(); should be enough
```

or even better because of the sessioncache usage

```
var user = session.Get<User>(id);
if (user == null)
    // user with given Id does not exist
```