# Linq to NHibernate: 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Entity]' cannot be converted

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have an entity with an interface:

```
public interface IStore
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Store : IStore
{
    public Store(int d)
    {

    }

    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }

    public Store()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
        Staff = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public virtual void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        product.StoresStockedIn.Add(this);
        Products.Add(product);
    }

    public virtual void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        employee.Store = this;
        Staff.Add(employee);
    }
}
```

and I have a specific method for Linq, returning a queryable of interfaces:

```
private static IQueryable<Store> GetStores(ISession session)
{
    return session.Query<Store>();
}
```

But Single() and First() methods do throw exceptions.

```
var stores = GetStores(session);
var s = stores.First(e => e.Id == 37); // crash
var s1 = stores.Single(e => e.Id == 37); // crash
```

Yields:

```
'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[TestFluentNhibernate.IStore]' cannot be converted to System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TestFluentNhibernate.Store]
```

`Where().ToList()` does work fine...

Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "Does not work"?

Comment: a have the exception in this command

Comment: You state queryable of interface (originally "collection of interface") but your code show it otherwise, queryable of classes instead. And have you mapped the interface, or only the classe? Better provide [mcve] please.

Comment: I have mapped the classes, but return it as the queryable of interfaces (and it works)

Comment: I have a problem after upgrade NH from 3.x to 4.0. If I query and cast the object to an interface and use ToList before query First/Single, it is running well, if not, it causes an error. I still don't know the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649781/nhibernate-throws-object-of-type-system-linq-enumerablequery1entity-cannot).

```
var s = stores.Where(e => e.Id == 37).ToList().First(); 
var s1 = stores.Where(e => e.Id == 37).ToList().Single();
```

may solve the problem.

Comment: I have done that (the question is too old), but it is just workaround, it is not a right way:( as I remember, it is just a bug of NH

Comment: Yes, ToList isn't a good solution. Do you remember how to solve this problem, @VVildVVolf?